# Any suitable replacements for IWantSandy yet?

Tags: webapp-rec

In 2008, I DIED. My personal assistant, Sandy, from http://iwantsandy.com was retired when the project was gobbled up by Twitter.

> For those who haven't had the pleasure
>   of meeting Sandy... she was a personal
>   planning assistant who functioned
>   primarily over email (but also twitter
>   and web interface). She was helpful
>   and not annoying.
>
> You could forward emails to her with
>   simple lines at the top like "remind
>   me to pick up the kids next tuesday"
>   or "r call my boss in 23 days" or "r
>   revisit this email in 1 year #review
>   , #2011-plans".
>
> She would let you know if she didn't
>   understand, but most of the time she
>   did. And she would send you reminders,
>   with the original email attached so
>   you can see what you were looking at
>   when you made the reminder. She'd also
>   deliver daily agendas if you wanted
>   them.
>
> She understood most commonly expressed
>   forms of time, recurring events ("r
>   take out the trash every tuesday
>   morning" or "r pay netflix every 90
>   days") and you could look at her
>   calendar to make adjustments if you
>   needed to move something.

I depended on Sandy and I never found a good replacement for her.

RTM handles emails to some degree though it's far pickier about how you phrase things than Sandy was and not nearly as simple. I also dislike how it does reminders and dislike its web interface.

I've also been playing with Springpad a lot but it's rather short on planning features.

Has anyone found anything like Sandy out there?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [reqall](http://www.reqall.com/) Adding a reminder by email is for Pro accounts only, but the free accounts lets you add items via IM, web, phone call, smartphone apps, and it's really good at handling natural language inputs. There is iCal support as well as Google Calendar integration.

Comment: pshh, I'd pay to get sandy back. $25 a year isn't bad at all. I'll check this out... thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

followupthen.com

Email "NextTuesday@followupthen.com" and next Tuesday you'll get that email back in your inbox. That service is free. For SMS service, I think you pay.